# How to duplicate values in a Map-like Structure and obtain all keys in a simple way

Tags: java, collections, shared-libraries, key-value

I'm looking for a way to obtain the keys of a Map with just a list of pair of values (or duplicated keys which is a synonym for me) as an array. I found myself generating this kind of implementation:

```
public static Integer[] pairOfValues(){
    class MyMap<T,E> extends ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<T,E>>{
        public ArrayList<T> keys(){
            try {
                ArrayList<T> keys=new ArrayList<>();
                this.forEach(entry -> { keys.add(entry.getKey()); });
                return keys;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Impossible to obtain keys from the ArrayList",e);
            }
        }
    }
    
    MyMap<Integer,String> myMap=new MyMap<>(){{
        add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(1,"a"));
        add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(1,"x"));
        add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(2,"b"));
        add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(2,"a"));
    }};

    ArrayList<Integer> onlyKeys=myMap.keys();
    Integer[] requiredArray=onlyKeys.toArray(new Integer[onlyKeys.size()]);
    return requiredArray;
}
```

Where I can just call the method `.keys()`.

#### Clarifying the objective

I'm sure I'm reinventing the weal here, but I was looking for a way to get the same goal as `List<Map.Entry<?,?>>` functionality (that basically is the same structure as a Map but that will allow duplicated keys) and also have the ability to obtain all keys from that simulated Map.

[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) has the method [keySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) although in the case of the custom implementation, I won't be getting the keys as a Set but as a List or some other collection that will allow duplicated data.

In summary:

1. It should be able to have duplicated values
2. I should be able to call a method within the instance and get all key values (including duplicated ones)
3. It must be simple to call/use

I'm sure there should be a library some one has already done (I don't know why there is not in Java already) that will help me accomplish this same without the need to create this kind of classes each time I need a pair of values.

I was looking online and I found this library [MultiValuedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html), where you can call the method keys().iterator() that will return just the keys but as an Iterator instead of a normal collection then I will need a for (which I have been looking to avoid from the beginning) to copy the values

Anyone here knows about a library or something that will help us with this kind of very common problems/solutions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: First of all, you are not using or creating a `Map`.  You have an `ArrayList` into which you put _tuples_ (key-value pairs) whose implementation you happened to borrow from `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.  It's hard to tell what you're trying to do, but I _think_ you want a "multi-map" data structure that allows multiple values per key Something like a `Map<K,List<V>>`.  Please clarify your ultimate goal.

Comment: I'm sorry (I though the code was clear enough :P) I updated the description so it will be more clear. The structure 1) should be able to have duplicated values 2) I should be able to call a method within the instance and get all key values (including duplicated ones) 3) I shouldn't need to iterate over the entries to extract the keys manually (and follow that spirit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) which has some classes that will work as an extension to the [JCF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html). I will specifically recommend [`LinkedHashMultimap<K,V>`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html) that, in case you are looking for all `keys` on your `Map`, you can get a [`Multiset<E>`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) calling the method `keys()`, this is a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html?is-external=true) and you can transform it into an array with the same method you are using.

The code that you will get from the example you are using will end up like this:

```
public static Integer[] pairOfValues(){
    com.google.common.collect.Multimap<Integer,String> myMap=LinkedHashMultimap.create();
    myMap.put(1,"a");
    myMap.put(1,"x");
    myMap.put(2,"b");
    myMap.put(2,"a");

    Multiset<Integer> onlyKeys=myMap.keys();
    Integer[] requiredArray=onlyKeys.toArray(new Integer[onlyKeys.size()]);
    return requiredArray;
}
```